# How to handle user defined errors from SQL Server in dbExpress?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I am using dbExpress to access SQL Server 2005/2008 database. 
I have raised a [user defined error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) message from trigger / stored procedure to my application:

```
raiserror 99999 "MSG"
```

By doing this I am getting exception like:

```
SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 99999
MSG
```

I have tried to fetch error code using below code but I am getting error code as 3604 not 99999:

```
if (pErrorObj.ErrorCode = 99999) then
   ShowMessage('Error');
```

How to retrieve this error code (99999) and its message (MSG)?

Comment: Did an actual SQL error (also) occur or are only you raising the 9999? 3604 is a 'duplicate key ignored' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275743%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: I am raising an error in certain scenario.